# JavaScript onchange function that updates data array and input value?

Tags: javascript, react-hooks, onchange

I'm creating an editable table to be used for scoring a boardgame called 7 Wonders. In the app I'm creating I've got a:

1. DataByPlayer.js: An array of objects for players 1-7. Each object will hold the individual score for each category area (military, armada, etc.).

```
{ 
playerId: '1',
name: 'Player 1',
military: 100,
armada: 0,
coins: 0,
wonders: 0,
blue: 0,
yellow: 0,
green: 0,
purple: 0,
boats: 0,
leaders: 0,
black: 0,
total: 0
}, 
...
```

2. The table itself which has an input inside each table cell.

   ```
    const ScoreTableByPlayer = () => {
    const Player1 = DataByPlayer[0];
    const Player2 = DataByPlayer[1];
    const Player3 = DataByPlayer[2];
    const Player4 = DataByPlayer[3];
    const Player5 = DataByPlayer[4];
    const Player6 = DataByPlayer[5];
    const Player7 = DataByPlayer[6];

    const calculatePlayerScore = (index) => {
        return DataByPlayer[index].military + DataByPlayer[index].armada + DataByPlayer[index].coins + DataByPlayer[index].wonders + DataByPlayer[index].blue + DataByPlayer[index].yellow + DataByPlayer[index].green + DataByPlayer[index].purple + DataByPlayer[index].boats + DataByPlayer[index].leaders + DataByPlayer[index].black;

    };

    return (
        <div class="tableFixHead">
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th id="firstCell"></th>
                        <th>
                            <input
                            name="name"
                            type="text"
                            placeholder="Player1"
                            />
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            <input
                            name="name"
                            type="text"
                            placeholder="Player2"
                            />
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            <input
                            name="name"
                            type="text"
                            placeholder="Player3"
                            />
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            <input
                            name="name"
                            type="text"
                            placeholder="Player4"
                            />
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            <input
                            name="name"
                            type="text"
                            placeholder="Player5"
                            />
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            <input
                            name="name"
                            type="text"
                            placeholder="Player6"
                            />
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            <input
                            name="name"
                            type="text"
                            placeholder="Player7"
                            />
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr class="militaryRow">
                        <th class="leftColumn militaryRow">
                            <img class="wondersIcon" 
                                src={icon_military} 
                                alt="military icon" 
                            /> 
                            <span class="categoryHeading">Military</span>
                        </th>
                        <td><input
                            name="Player1.military"
                            value={Player1.military}
                            type="number"
                        />
                        </td>
                        <td><input
                            name="Player2.military"
                            value={Player2.military}
                            type="number"            
                        />
                        </td>
                        <td><input
                            name="Player3.military"
                            value={Player3.military}
                            type="number"            
                        />
                        </td>
                        <td><input
                            name="Player4.military"
                            value={Player4.military}
                            type="number"            
                        />
                        </td>
                        <td><input
                            name="Player5.military"
                            value={Player5.military}
                            type="number"            
                        />
                        </td>
                        <td><input
                            name="Player6.military"
                            value={Player6.military}
                            type="number"            
                        />
                        </td>
                        <td><input
                            name="Player7.military"
                            value={Player7.military}
                            type="number"            
                        />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="armadaRow">
                        <th class="leftColumn armadaRow">
                            <img class="wondersIcon" 
                                src={icon_armada} 
                                alt="armada icon" /> 
                            <span class="categoryHeading">Armada</span>
                        </th>
                        <td><input
                            class="player1 armada"
                            value={Player1.armada}
                            type="number"                     
                        /></td>
                        <td><input
                            class="player2 armada"
                            value={Player2.armada}
                            type="number"                     
                        /></td>
                        <td><input
                            class="player3 armada"
                            value={Player3.armada}
                            type="number"                     
                        /></td>
                        <td><input
                            class="player4 armada"
                            value={Player4.armada}
                            type="number"                     
                        /></td>
                        <td><input
                            class="player5 armada"
                            value={Player5.armada}
                            type="number"                     
                        /></td>
                        <td><input
                            class="player6 armada"
                            value={Player6.armada}
                            type="number"                     
                        /></td>
                        <td><input
                            class="player7 armada"
                            value={Player7.armada}
                            type="number"                     
                        /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="coinsRow">
                        <th class="leftColumn coinsRow">
                            <img class="wondersIcon" 
                                src={icon_coins} 
                                alt="coins icon" /> 
                            <span class="categoryHeading">Coins & Minus Points</span>
                        </th>
                        <td><input
                            class="player1 coins"
                            value={Player1.coins}
                            type="number"                     
                        /></td>
                        <td><input
                            class="player2 coins"
                            value={Player2.coins}
                            type="number"                     
                        /></td>
                        <td><input
                            class="player3 coins"
                            value={Player3.coins}
                            type="number"                     
                        /></td>
                        <td><input
                            class="player4 coins"
                            value={Player4.coins}
                            type="number"                     
                        /></td>
                        <td><input
                            class="player5 coins"
                            value={Player5.coins}
                            type="number"                     
                        /></td>
                        <td><input
                            class="player6 coins"
                            value={Player6.coins}
                            type="number"                     
                        /></td>
                        <td><input
                            class="player7 coins"
                            value={Player7.coins}
                            type="number"                     
                        /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="wondersRow">
                        <th class="leftColumn wondersRow">
                            <img class="wondersIcon" 
                                src={icon_wonders} 
                                alt="wonders icon" /> 
                            <span class="categoryHeading">Wonders Board</span>
                        </th>
                        <td><input
                            class="player1 wonders"
                            value={Player1.wonders}
                            type="number"                     
                        /></td>
                        <td><input
                            class="player2 wonders"
                            value={Player2.wonders}
                            type="number"                     
                        /></td>
                        <td><input
                            class="player3 wonders"
                            value={Player3.wonders}
                            type="number"                     
                        /></td>
                        <td><input
                            class="player4 wonders"
                            value={Player4.wonders}
                            type="number"                     
                        /></td>
                        <td><input
                            class="player5 wonders"
                            value={Player5.wonders}
                            type="number"                     
                        /></td>
                        <td><input
                            class="player6 wonders"
                            value={Player6.wonders}
                            type="number"                     
                        /></td>
                        <td><input
                            class="player7 wonders"
                            value={Player7.wonders}
                            type="number"                     
                        /></td>

                    </tr>
                    <tr class="civicRow">
                        <th class="leftColumn civicRow">
                            <img class="wondersIcon" 
                                src={icon_blue} 
                                alt="civic icon" /> 
                            <span class="categoryHeading">Civic Cards</span>
                        </th>
                        <td><input
                            class="player1 blue"
                            value={Player1.blue}
                            type="number"                     
                        /></td>
                        <td><input
                            class="player2 blue"
                            value={Player2.blue}
                            type="number"                     
                        /></td>
                        <td><input
                            class="player3 blue"
                            value={Player3.blue}
                            type="number"                     
                        /></td>
                        <td><input
                            class="player4 blue"
                            value={Player4.blue}
                            type="number"                     
                        /></td>
                        <td><input
                            class="player5 blue"
                            value={Player5.blue}
                            type="number"                     
                        /></td>
                        <td><input
                            class="player6 blue"
                            value={Player6.blue}
                            type="number"                     
                        /></td>
                        <td><input
                            class="player7 blue"
                            value={Player7.blue}
                            type="number"                     
                        /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="commercialRow">
                        <th class="leftColumn commercialRow">
                            <img class="wondersIcon" 
                                src={icon_yellow} 
                                alt="commerical icon" /> 
                            <span class="categoryHeading">Commerical Cards</span>
                        </th>
                        <td><input
                            class="player1 yellow"
                            value={Player1.yellow}
                            type="number"                     
                        /></td>
                        <td><input
                            class="player2 yellow"
                            value={Player2.yellow}
                            type="number"                     
                        /></td>
                        <td><input
                            class="player3 yellow"
                            value={Player3.yellow}
                            type="number"                     
                        /></td>
                        <td><input
                            class="player4 yellow"
                            value={Player4.yellow}
                            type="number"                     
                        /></td>
                        <td><input
                            class="player5 yellow"
                            value={Player5.yellow}
                            type="number"                     
                        /></td>
                        <td><input
                            class="player6 yellow"
                            value={Player6.yellow}
                            type="number"                     
                        /></td>
                        <td><input
                            class="player7 yellow"
                            value={Player7.yellow}
                            type="number"                     
                        /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="scientificRow">
                        <th class="leftColumn scientificRow">
                            <img class="wondersIcon" 
                                src={icon_green} 
                                alt="scientific icon" /> 
                            <span class="categoryHeading">Scientific Points</span>
                        </th>
                        <td><input
                            class="player1 green"
                            value={Player1.green}
                            type="number"                     
                        /></td>
                        <td><input
                            class="player2 green"
                            value={Player2.green}
                            type="number"                     
                        /></td>
                        <td><input
                            class="player3 green"
                            value={Player3.green}
                            type="number"                     
                        /></td>
                        <td><input
                            class="player4 green"
                            value={Player4.green}
                            type="number"                     
                        /></td>
                        <td><input
                            class="player5 green"
                            value={Player5.green}
                            type="number"                     
                        /></td>
                        <td><input
                            class="player6 green"
                            value={Player6.green}
                            type="number"                     
                        /></td>
                        <td><input
                            class="player7 green"
                            value={Player7.green}
                            type="number"                     
                        /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="guildRow">
                        <th class="leftColumn guildRow">
                            <img class="wondersIcon" 
                                src={icon_purple} 
                                alt="guild icon" /> 
                            <span class="categoryHeading">Guild Cards</span>
                        </th>
                        <td><input
                            class="player1 purple"
                            value={Player1.purple}
                            type="number"                     
                        /></td>
                        <td><input
                            class="player2 purple"
                            value={Player2.purple}
                            type="number"                     
                        /></td>
                        <td><input
                            class="player3 purple"
                            value={Player3.purple}
                            type="number"                     
                        /></td>
                        <td><input
                            class="player4 purple"
                            value={Player4.purple}
                            type="number"                     
                        /></td>
                        <td><input
                            class="player5 purple"
                            value={Player5.purple}
                            type="number"                     
                        /></td>
                        <td><input
                            class="player6 purple"
                            value={Player6.purple}
                            type="number"                     
                        /></td>
                        <td><input
                            class="player7 purple"
                            value={Player7.purple}
                            type="number"                     
                        /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="boatRow">
                        <th class="leftColumn boatRow">
                            <img class="wondersIcon" 
                                src={icon_boats} 
                                alt="boats icon" /> 
                            <span class="categoryHeading">Boats & Islands</span>
                        </th>
                        <td><input
                            class="player1 boats"
                            value={Player1.boats}
                            type="number"                     
                        /></td>
                        <td><input
                            class="player2 boats"
                            value={Player2.boats}
                            type="number"                     
                        /></td>
                        <td><input
                            class="player3 boats"
                            value={Player3.boats}
                            type="number"                     
                        /></td>
                        <td><input
                            class="player4 boats"
                            value={Player4.boats}
                            type="number"                     
                        /></td>
                        <td><input
                            class="player5 boats"
                            value={Player5.boats}
                            type="number"                     
                        /></td>
                        <td><input
                            class="player6 boats"
                            value={Player6.boats}
                            type="number"                     
                        /></td>
                        <td><input
                            class="player7 boats"
                            value={Player7.boats}
                            type="number"                     
                        /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="leaderRow">
                        <th class="leftColumn leaderRow">
                            <img class="wondersIcon" 
                                src={icon_leaders} 
                                alt="leaders icon" /> 
                            <span class="categoryHeading">Leader Cards</span>
                        </th>
                        <td><input
                            class="player1 leaders"
                            value={Player1.leaders}
                            type="number"                     
                        /></td>
                        <td><input
                            class="player2 leaders"
                            value={Player2.leaders}
                            type="number"                     
                        /></td>
                        <td><input
                            class="player3 leaders"
                            value={Player3.leaders}
                            type="number"                     
                        /></td>
                        <td><input
                            class="player4 leaders"
                            value={Player4.leaders}
                            type="number"                     
                        /></td>
                        <td><input
                            class="player5 leaders"
                            value={Player5.leaders}
                            type="number"                     
                        /></td>
                        <td><input
                            class="player6 leaders"
                            value={Player6.leaders}
                            type="number"                     
                        /></td>
                        <td><input
                            class="player7 leaders"
                            value={Player7.leaders}
                            type="number"                     
                        /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="citiesRow">
                        <th class="leftColumn citiesRow">
                            <img class="wondersIcon" 
                                src={icon_black} 
                                alt="cities icon" /> 
                            <span class="categoryHeading">Cities Cards</span>
                        </th>
                        <td><input
                            class="player1 black"
                            value={Player1.black}
                            type="number"                     
                        /></td>
                        <td><input
                            class="player2 black"
                            value={Player2.black}
                            type="number"                     
                        /></td>
                        <td><input
                            class="player3 black"
                            value={Player3.black}
                            type="number"                     
                        /></td>
                        <td><input
                            class="player4 black"
                            value={Player4.black}
                            type="number"                     
                        /></td>
                        <td><input
                            class="player5 black"
                            value={Player5.black}
                            type="number"                     
                        /></td>
                        <td><input
                            class="player6 black"
                            value={Player6.black}
                            type="number"                     
                        /></td>
                        <td><input
                            class="player7 black"
                            value={Player7.black}
                            type="number"                     
                        /></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
                <tfoot>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="leftColumn totalHeadingCell"><span class="totalHeading">Total</span></th>
                        <td>{calculatePlayerScore(0)}</td>
                        <td>{calculatePlayerScore(1)}</td>
                        <td>{calculatePlayerScore(2)}</td>
                        <td>{calculatePlayerScore(3)}</td>
                        <td>{calculatePlayerScore(4)}</td>
                        <td>{calculatePlayerScore(5)}</td>
                        <td>{calculatePlayerScore(6)}</td>
                    </tr>
                </tfoot>
            </table>
        </div>
    )
   };

   export default ScoreTableByPlayer;`
   ```

**The Problem:**

is that when you try and change the value of one of the inputs, I cannot get it to:
A) Change the value in the data array (See above)
B) Show the updated value as the input value.

You can check out:

- [Github](https://github.com/Patchalv/7-wonders_scorecard_v3)
- [Live](https://7wonders-scorecard.netlify.app/)

I presume I need to create an onchange function but after days of searching online and trying everything I cannot get anything to work.

Comment: What did you try that didn't work?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at async storage, you should be able to set the new value with onChangeText and then get your data from async storage with the getItem method

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: But it's for a numbers input?

Comment: You can add numbers with async storage